# Visual studio designer: type is not marked as serializable

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working with Visual studio 2008.

I have a form inherited from DockContent class (Weifen Luo dock panel suite if you ever heard about that library).

I can add another controls on that form. But when I tried to add an event handler via Property tab, Visual studio generated an exception "type is not marked as serializable".

What should I do to fix that problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the class you are working with has the [Serializable] attribute.  Because events are non-serializable, you will have to mark them this way.

[field:NonSerialized]
private EventHandler myEvent;